# Analytical value of minima for a function involving Logarithm and exponential

Tags: optimization, logarithms, exponential-function, maxima-minima

I am trying to derive the analytical expression for the point of minima of the function
$$\frac{c+ x \ln(-2+2 e^{c/x})-\ln (-1+e^{2c/x})}{x [\ln(-1+e^{c/x})-\ln (-1+e^{2c/x}) ]} $$
Here $x$ is the variable and $c$ is a constant. Plot of the function for a specific $c$ value is shown in the figure:
[image]
Mathematica code:

```
(c + x (Log[-2 + 2 E^(c/x)] - 
Log[-1 + E^((2 c)/x)]))/(x (Log[-1 + E^(c/x)] - 
Log[-1 + E^((2 c)/x)]))
```

Any help will be appreciated. I have also asked this question on [mathematica stack exchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/229315/analytical-value-of-maxima-of-a-function-involving-logarithm-and-exponential).

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/229317/9362

Comment: The MATHEMATICA formula is slightly different from the question formula $$\frac{x \left(\log \left(2 e^{c/x}-2\right)-\log \left(e^{\frac{2 c}{x}}-1\right)\right)+c}{x \left(\log
   \left(e^{c/x}-1\right)-\log \left(e^{\frac{2 c}{x}}-1\right)\right)}$$ . Which is correct?

Comment: @Cesareo Mathematica one. Sorry for the typo/mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making $y = e^{\frac cx}$ after some simplifications like $\ln(y^2-1) = \ln(y-1)+\ln(y+1)$ we have

$$
f(y) = 1-\frac{\ln(2 y)}{\ln(y+1)}
$$

[image]

with graphics shown in blue. Now the minimum for $f(y)$ (using an iterative method) is attained at $y^*=e^{\frac {c}{x^*}} \approx 3.4034978790622934$

then

$$
x^* \approx \frac{c}{\ln(3.4034978790622934)}
$$